# Spouse Visa Options When Working In USA

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian Citizen currently residing in Canada being interviewed for a job in the US. My girlfriend is a Chinese Citizen, currently on a student visa in Canada (part of a Masters program). What visa options do I have so that my girlfriend can come with me to the US should I get a job offer? What kind of visas would let her apply for jobs (or apply for college programs) once she is in the US? I we were to get married, would it give us a wider selection of options?

Comment: I think this is better placed in expats.se

Comment: If this is the case, please feel free to migrate my question.

Answer (score 1):

> What visa options do I have so that my girlfriend can come with me to
>   the US should I get a job offer?

She could try to get some visa on her own, independently of yours, but she would not get any additional options because of your visa. *Girlfriend* is not a legal status and as such not recognized by USCIS.

> I we were to get married, would it give us a wider selection of
>   options?

Yes, work visas have accompanying family visas for spouse and children. For example a spouse of person working on [H-1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) or similar H visa would get dependent [H4 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-4_visa), while spouse of someone on [L-1 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-1_visa) would get [L-2 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-2_visa).

Comment: There's also the TD visa for dependents of TN (NAFTA) professionals.  See http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/employment/nafta.html.